# Report Automation for Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We have Automation framework configured using Selenium Webdriver for our project. And use Junit as test engine and Aapache-ant to build and run the Java class files. 
Ant generates a HTML-Junit report when Scripts run from console using Build.xml.

We are currently unable to get the required detailed output using ANT report.

We are looking to generate HTML report which provides detailed test results and also display in some interactive format to read and understand the results. For example the report should fulfill below,
•   Summary of
1.  Test case Passed
2.  Test Failed 
3.  Test Not executed

•   Detailed report displaying columns  for
1.  Test Case ID
2.  Test Case Description [Irrespective of the class/function name]
3.  Results /Status

Please help us in providing your valuable insights in configuring the Selenium web driver to meet above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

TestNg Xlst is the best choice for you. 
Download testng-results.xsl from "https://code.google.com/p/testng-xslt/" and put it in your source folder.
and add a target in your Ant build file like

```
<target name="testng-xslt-report">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt">
        </delete>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt">
        </mkdir>
        <xslt in="${basedir}/test-output/testng-results.xml" style="${basedir}/src/testng-results.xsl" out="${basedir}/testng-xslt/index.html">
            <param expression="${basedir}/testng-xslt/" name="testNgXslt.outputDir" />
            <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" />
            <param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" />
            <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" />
            <classpath refid="Automation_DataDriven.classpath">
            </classpath>
        </xslt>
    </target>
```

Note:- 
1.  Before doing this operation you should be having your report xml file already. Because TestNg-Xslt just modifies your existing report in desired beutiful format
2.  Point that file in "in" attribute of  node , like for my case it was under
         "${basedir}/test-output/"  so I have written 
3.  Last but not least, I'm not sure that for junit engine it will work (though, I have given work arroud in note 1 and 2). For TestNg it works fine, so please let me know, if it works for junit also or the problem you face for the same.

Also I would suggest to use TesNg over Junit. For knowing benefits, google is the best option.